# CSS inheritance, or something like that

Tags: css

This is probably silly question, but here it goes.

I have 3 ID in my css file, and they all have some same code. For example:

```
#ID1 {
    // some code
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}    
#ID2 {
    // some code
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}    
#ID3 {
    // some code
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

MY question is: is is possible to make some class or ID in CSS and call it inside another CSS class or ID. For example:

```
#setting {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
#ID1 {
    .setting        
    // some code
}    
#ID2 {
    .setting  
    // some code
}    
#ID3 {
    .setting  
    // some code
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not at this time, but there's LESS.css and SASS.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called LESS. Read about it [here](http://lesscss.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You can override css by applying reference to its parent class, check below example :

```
#setting {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
}
#ID1 .setting {
   // some code
}    
#ID2 .setting  {
   // some code
}    
#ID3 .setting  {
   // some code
}
```

above code will apply all the "setting" class tag inside ID1, ID2, ID3 respectively.
If your "setting" child is immediate class then you can you below as example :

```
#setting {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
}
#ID1 > .setting {
   // some code
}    
#ID2 > .setting  {
   // some code
}    
#ID3 > .setting  {
   // some code
}
```

Above code will only apply to its immediate child named with class "setting".

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple CSS classes on a single element.

You can create the "generic" classes and apply them to the elements.

For  example:

```
<div class="class1 class2">some content</div>
```

Remember that if there is a common property in class1 and class2, the value of that property in class2 will overwrite the one in class1 on that element and ultimately the element will have the value defined in class2.

Really old browsers don't support this but most probably you shouldn't worry about them.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible in CSS, and it has nothing to do with inheritance. In CSS rules, you put all the selectors before the “{” and only declarations (*property* : *value*) between “{” and “}”.

But you can use both an `id` attribute and a `class` attribute on an element, as in

```
<div id="ID1" class="setting">...</div>
```

and then if you have e.g.

```
.setting {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

(note: `.` not `#`), these declarations are applied to all elements with `class=setting`, along with any other declarations that may apply due to other CSS rules.